# Decode H.264 without stream

Tags: windows, h.264

I have an application wherein I have H.264 frames from an RTSP stream stored in a proprietary database. I need to be able to present a frame to the H.264 decoder (frames in sequence, of course) and get back the decoded frame (bitmap, whatever) output. I cannot use the traditional DirectShow streams because I don't have a stream. Is there any codec can be used in this manner? Later I will need to go the other way as well (given bitmaps or other format images, create an H.264 stream). Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it really impossible to build a stream "shim" between your database and your application?

Answer (score 1):

Create a DirectShow Source Filter that assembles the h264 stream from database, then you can pass it to standard DirectShow H264 decoder. Look into DirectShow samples for example source code.

Answer (score 1):

As Isso mentioned already, you can push the H.264 data into DirectShow pipeline and have the frame decoded. Additionally to this, there is [H.264 Video Decoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MFT (Windows 7 and more recent only) which might be an easier way to use the decoder and to apply it to an individual "frame". You can use other decoders as well, such as `FFmpeg`/`libavcodec` however you would still need to interface to the decoders typically designed for stream processing.